# Playing S3 audio with Expo-AV

Tags: react-native, expo, aws-amplify

I'm trying to play an  audio from my aws s3 bucket with the use of expo-av but it deosnt work. It's my first time using expo-av but I believe the issue lies in pointing the source url to my aws API. Below is my code. I'm quite sure I screwed up here so an explanation to the answer will be very much appreciated.

```
 Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(true)

    Audio.setAudioModeAsync(
      {playsInSilentModeIOS : true,
        allowsRecordingIOS : true,
        staysActiveInBackground : true,
        interruptionModeIOS : {
          interruptionModeIOS : true,
          INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX: true,
          INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DUCK_OTHERS: true,
        },
        interruptionModeAndroid : {
          INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX: true,
          INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DUCK_OTHERS: true,

        },
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true,
      }
    )

    export default class Audiol extends Component {

    state = {
        ...
      };

   componentDidMount() {
    Storage.get(this.props.a)
            .then(result =>{ console.log("Storageb");
             const Me = result;
             this.setState({Audio: Me})
             console.warn("geb")

            })
            .catch(err => console.log("S.ERROR",err))

    }

    async handleaudio() {
      const soundObject = new Audio.Sound;
        try {
          soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(onPlaybackStatusUpdate);
          await soundObject.loadAsync({uri: this.state.Audio}, {}, true);

          console.warn("success")
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn("error", error, this.state.Audio)
          // An error occurred!
        }      
      }
```

UPDATE:
        Just noticed that this error only occours when I use `this.state.Audio` if I use say the exact link given by `state.Audio` in the below manner it works.

```
await soundObject.loadAsync({uri: 'https://...amazonaws.com/...'});
```

But I need it to work with state.

Hope some one can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide us the result of `this.state.audio` during your `try`?

Also can you try the following code inside your `handleaudio` function:

`const myAudio =  Audio.Sound.createAsync({uri: this.state.Audio}, {}, true);
 myAudio.playbackInstance.playAsync()`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply but unfortunately still gettting thesame error. The erro message is                               `Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.Audio') `

Comment: Arf..to go deeper some questions. I don't get it where you set your `audio` state ? And just a typo question why are you using `Audio` rather than `audio`?

Comment: I set the `Audio` state inside `componentDidMount()` and I use `Audio` cause i named the state `Audio`. I hope I answered your question right cuz I'm not really sure I understood what you meant. Thanks!

Comment: What the result of `this.props.a`? and your `const Me` ?

Comment: `this.props.a` is the key for the file in the bucket and `const Me` is the link returned by `Storage.get`

Comment: Ok but your link should be similar to an aws link, is it the case? Or do you get `undefined` ? Can you print the value of `Me` ?

Comment: if i copy the link and replace it with `this.state.audio` the audio is returned that's what baffles me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198132/discussion-between-morissetcl-and-jibidijib).